# QGIS: Python numpy error when installing plugin

Tags: qgis, python, qgis-plugins, error, runtimeerror

I want to install the plugin "UMEP", but it results in this error:

```
An error has occurred while executing Python code: 

RuntimeError: module compiled against API version 0xe but this version of numpy is 0xd 
RuntimeError: module compiled against API version 0xe but this version of numpy is 0xd


Python version: 3.7.0 (v3.7.0:1bf9cc5093, Jun 27 2018, 04:59:51) [MSC v.1914 64 bit (AMD64)] 
QGIS version: 3.16.4-Hannover Hannover, 654e76b3cb
```

Seems like a problem with numpy, I tried `pip install numpy --upgrade` in the windows command window, but it didn't solve the problem. You guys got any ideas?

Comment: To install/upgrade packages in the QGIS environment you can use the OSGeo4W shell (it will pop up if you search it in the start menu). However, be careful, tampering with package versions shipped with QGIS might break QGIS itself.